# How to navigate to other pages with header buttons in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to navigate between screens using buttons on the header? When I try to go back or navigate to other pages using header buttons I get the same error.
The buttons on the screen work perfectly.

"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
(Device)"

"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.goBack')"

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import  React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

//Screen 1
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

//Screen 2
function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details</Text>
      <Button title="back home" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App({ navigation, route }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRout="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />


        <Stack.Screen
          name="Details"
          component={DetailsScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: () => <Text>Register</Text>,
            headerRight: () => <Button title="Test" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />,
            headerLeft: () => <Button title="back home" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />,
          }}
        />


      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/@camileppst/navigation-test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to inject the navigation props, not getting it from the props of the App component:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRout="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Details"
          component={DetailsScreen}
          options={({navigation}) => ({
            headerTitle: () => <Text>Register</Text>,
            headerRight: () => <Button title="Test" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />,
            headerLeft: () => <Button title="back home" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />,
          })}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: How can I disable such a button via a parameter I have passed to the page Details from the previous page? In other words I want  to control the header button via a navigation parameter that I pass from the previous page.

Comment: you can try using the setOptions with in the component to. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions